# how to make Balloon ToolTip in SilverlightApplication?

Tags: c#, silverlight

i'm trying to make a balloon tooltip with close button in a silverlight web application.... how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/10/18/customizing-a-tooltip.aspx) on how to customize the tooltip. Basically you:

> set the ToolTip's Template property to a fancy new Template which is defined in the page resources.

The code is this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToolTipTemplate">
        <Border>
            <Grid>
                -- other stuff --
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and then to use it:

```
    <TextBox Height="20" Width="100">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Template="{StaticResource ToolTipTemplate}">
                <ToolTip.Content>
                    <TextBlock 
                       Text="This is a longer string of text." 
                       FontFamily="Georgia" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </ToolTip.Content>
            </ToolTip>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </TextBox>
```

(code copied from the blog entry).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article recently, that shows a balloon tool tip, which can be placed over any FrameworkElement in Silverlight. Also the alignment can be changed using the Alignment property in Balloon.

[Notification Control in Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320232/Notification-Control-in-Silverlight)

Comment: Could you please edit in some disclosure that you wrote the post at the given link.